# Lo sisgodedu by varying practices of heiche kedusha?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefillah-betzibbur, heiche-kedusha

In a minyan (quorum) that is doing *heiche kedushe* with the (inevitable?) scenario that some mispallelim (ones praying) are following the Rama and waiting till after the chazzan's kedusha to begin their silent amidah while some are following the Sefardi/Brisker minhag (custom) to daven (pray) the first 3 brachot (blessings) together with the chazzan, are the minority violating the prohibition of "*[lo sisgodedu](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/kiseitzei.html)*"?

Comment: You're implying that the minhag defines what's considered tefilla betzibbur rather than what one SHOULD do lechatchillah. If it's the latter, it's certainly not a violation, since everyone is still considered conjoined for kedushah

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I believe we generally require the 1st blessing (avot) to be recited together to be considered tefilla betzibbur...